# Why tcolorbox listings (\newtcblisting) prints ^I instead of tabs, despite setting 'showtabs=false'?

Tags: tabs, latex, xelatex, listings

When I use the listings package to print this snippet everything is fine, but when I use \newtcblisting, tabs are printed as '^I' in the resulting pdf. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
\lstdefinestyle{codestyle}{
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=8,
    showstringspaces=false,
}
\newtcblisting{code}[2][Python]{%
    title=#2,
    fonttitle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    listing options={style=codestyle,language=#1}}

%In the document body 
\begin{code}{polls/urls.py}
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index')
    ]
\end{code}
```

```
from django .urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
^^Ipath('',views .index ,name='index ')
^^I]
```

I have written a package in that I define environments and styles in it. When I use the package for a test.tex file in which only a single snippet of code is placed, everything is fine. However, For my main large document, what I described above happens. Here's the log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex 2022.7.9)  16 JUL 2022 20:36
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**report.tex
(./report.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-10>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\c@figure=\count187
\c@table=\count188
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (./studynotes.sty
Package: studynotes 2022/07/14

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2020-07-07 v1.5u LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks16
\verbatim@line=\toks17
\verbatim@in@stream=\read2
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 227.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2022/04/12 v5.0l Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count189
\Gm@cntv=\count190
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count191
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen139
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen140
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen141
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen143
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen144
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen146
\Gm@dimlist=\toks19
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realboxes/realboxes.sty
Package: realboxes 2011/08/08 v0.2 Change box commands to read there content as
 real boxes

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty
Package: collectbox 2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
\collectedbox=\box50
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty
Package: adjcalc 2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back
-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks20
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks21
)
\XKV@depth=\count192
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))))
(/home/matin/texmf/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
Package: tcolorbox 2022/06/24 version 5.1.1 text color boxes

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks22
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen147
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen148

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
Package: pgf 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen149
\Gin@req@width=\dimen150
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks23
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks24

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks25
))
\pgf@x=\dimen151
\pgf@y=\dimen152
\pgf@xa=\dimen153
\pgf@ya=\dimen154
\pgf@xb=\dimen155
\pgf@yb=\dimen156
\pgf@xc=\dimen157
\pgf@yc=\dimen158
\pgf@xd=\dimen159
\pgf@yd=\dimen160
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read3
\c@pgf@counta=\count193
\c@pgf@countb=\count194
\c@pgf@countc=\count195
\c@pgf@countd=\count196
\t@pgf@toka=\toks26
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks27
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks28
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count197

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-xetex.def

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
File: pgfsys-xetex.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
File: pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
\pgfsys@objnum=\count198
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count199
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count266
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen161
\pgfmath@count=\count267
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks29
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks30
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks31
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count268
)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen162
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen163
\pgf@picminy=\dimen164
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen165
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen166
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen167
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen168
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen169
\pgf@xx=\dimen170
\pgf@xy=\dimen171
\pgf@yx=\dimen172
\pgf@yy=\dimen173
\pgf@zx=\dimen174
\pgf@zy=\dimen175
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen176
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen177
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen178
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen179
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count269
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen180
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.t
ex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen181
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen182
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen183
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen184
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@max=\dimen185
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count270
\pgf@shadingcount=\count271
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen186
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen187
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
)
\@envbody=\toks32
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count272
)
\tcb@titlebox=\box58
\tcb@upperbox=\box59
\tcb@lowerbox=\box60
\tcb@phantombox=\box61
\c@tcbbreakpart=\count273
\c@tcblayer=\count274
\c@tcolorbox@number=\count275
\tcb@temp=\box62
\tcb@temp=\box63
\tcb@temp=\box64
\tcb@temp=\box65
)
(/home/matin/texmf/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistings.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistings.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(/home/matin/texmf/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
\lst@mode=\count276
\lst@gtempboxa=\box66
\lst@token=\toks33
\lst@length=\count277
\lst@currlwidth=\dimen188
\lst@column=\count278
\lst@pos=\count279
\lst@lostspace=\dimen189
\lst@width=\dimen190
\lst@newlines=\count280
\lst@lineno=\count281
\lst@maxwidth=\dimen191

(/home/matin/texmf/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty
File: lstmisc.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
\c@lstnumber=\count282
\lst@skipnumbers=\count283
\lst@framebox=\box67
)
(/home/matin/texmf/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg
File: listings.cfg 2020/03/24 1.8d listings configuration
))
Package: listings 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)

(/home/matin/texmf/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistingscore.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(/home/matin/texmf/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbprocessing.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbprocessing.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
))
\c@tcblisting=\count284
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty
Package: footmisc 2022/03/08 v6.0d a miscellany of footnote facilities
\FN@temptoken=\toks34
\footnotemargin=\dimen192
\@outputbox@depth=\dimen193
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style bringhurst on input line 695.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style chicago on input line 703.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style wiley on input line 712.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style lamport-robust on input line 723.

Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style lamport* on input line 743.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style lamport*-robust on input line 764
.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2022-04-14 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count285
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count286
\g__graphics_track_int=\count287
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box68
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count288
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count289
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count290
) (./report.aux)
\openout1 = `report.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 7
.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(89.62709pt, 418.25368pt, 89.6271pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(101.40665pt, 591.5302pt, 152.11pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=418.25368pt
* \textheight=591.5302pt
* \oddsidemargin=17.3571pt
* \evensidemargin=17.3571pt
* \topmargin=-7.86334pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=35.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

\c@lstlisting=\count291
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/lmtt/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `TU/lmtt/b/n' tried instead on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 11.

Overfull \hbox (6.58235pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--12
\TU/lmr/m/n/12 recommended fork of MySQL. We run the installation command [][][
][][][]
 []

\tcb@out=\write4
\openout4 = `report.listing'.

(/home/matin/texmf/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty
File: lstlang1.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d listings language file
)
(/home/matin/texmf/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty
File: lstlang1.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d listings language file
) (./report.listing)
\openout4 = `report.listing'.


(./report.listing)
\openout4 = `report.listing'.

 (./report.listing) [1

]
\openout4 = `report.listing'.

 (./report.listing)
\openout4 = `report.listing'.

 (./report.listing)
\openout4 = `report.listing'.

(./report.listing) [2]
\openout4 = `report.listing'.

 (./report.listing)
\openout4 = `report.listing'.

 (./report.listing) [3]
\openout4 = `report.listing'.


(./report.listing)
\openout4 = `report.listing'.

 (/home/matin/texmf/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty
File: lstlang1.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d listings language file
)
(./report.listing) [4]
\openout4 = `report.listing'.

 (./report.listing) [5] (./report.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14606 strings out of 476156
 294842 string characters out of 5814964
 872172 words of memory out of 5000000
 35100 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 472115 words of font info for 52 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 114i,9n,118p,817b,1626s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on report.pdf (5 pages).
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]. If I puzzle together your code fragments, they work fine.

Comment: Please also do show your .log  file

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added the log and more explanations. My main .tex file seems to be okay and compiles without error, but the issue remains.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Nope, I was wrong. The tab was automatically replaced by spaces in the editor. The problem with tabs persists.

Comment: Ahh, xelatex. Are you using the `-8bit` option to compile your document?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Just regular < $ xelatex file.tex > command

Comment: Then please do try with `xelatex -8bit file`

Comment: (or switch to another compiler like lualatex)

Comment: This solved the problem. Thanks! May I ask what was the issue and is xelatex outdated or something?

Comment: You can find some background about the issue at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352063/listings-package-in-xelatex-every-tab-in-lstlisting-compiles-to-i-in-the-pd

Comment: xelatex is not exactly outdated, but it is the troublemaker amongst the tex engines. I don't see a good reason to use it. For normal documents, pdflatex works just fine. If one needs anything special, like system fonts, one can use lualatex instead. It is also much more powerful then xelatex.